# Create a table with PHP/MySQL which counts more than one variable

Tags: mysql, sql, count

i am currently starting to learn some basic php/mysql and i wonder if i am able to use the code like that? If i sell the article 5 times now and my turnover is 13$ would it count in the table as 5 soldtotal and 65 turnovertotal or would it be merged together as 70?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test SELECT
    article, turnover
    COUNT(*) AS soldtotal, turnovertotal
```

I did not find the answer on the internet, i guess iwasnt smart enough to google that

Comment: Well 1) we can't see your data so we can't tell if your figures are correct, and 2) have you tested the SELECT statement to see what you get? If you want to know if something works, generally the best way is to try it. If you need a bit more help from us, we would need a bit more detail, including some sample data. See also [ask] and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). Thanks.

Comment: Also, which of the stated outcomes do you actually want? It's wasn't entirely clear. At a guess, you maybe need to learn about the GROUP BY clause, but it's all a bit murky without more info.

Comment: I wanz both values to ne saved in the Table. So 5 for soldtotal and 65 for turnovertotal

Comment: ok. So what result are you getting right now when you run it? Again, bear in mind we cannot see your data or your table design.